# bash script to auto mkdir on usb

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to have auto script to open dir on any removable device - different usb have different names and i want the user only to enter the device name since the path /media/user is a default in most os linux sys. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
F= `zenity --entry`
mkdir /media/user/${F}/new+directory
```

the interpreter doesn't recognize the variable - any solution / suggestions?

Comment: /media is no longer the default mount point of removable devices in either Ubuntu or Fedora. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/336518/why-has-ubuntu-moved-the-default-mount-points

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after the `=`. Space separates commands from assignments in bash.

```
F=`zenity --entry`
```