# Creating folders on an ext2 unjournaled drive

Tags: partitioning, permissions, filesystem

I'm currently trying to create a writeable folder on a ext2 drive.

I took a usb drive and formatted it to ext3 using gparted.

Then I went into terminal and wrote in

```
sudo mkfs.ext2 -j -I 128 /dev/...
```

To make it an ext2 unjournaled drive.

Now I would like to make a writeable folder on that drive.

I know I should write in the command line `sudo mkdir [link to drive]`

My question is, where is the drive link? the code that directs terminal to the drive? Where can i find that?

I'm working on delivering a film to a cinema in a special format.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you plug in the USB drive, the filesystem should be mounted (made useable) in a folder under `/media/[whatever your username is]`. In 12.04 (and earlier), it's just a folder in `/media`.

If it is not mounted there automatically, mount it with `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /path/to/mountpoint` where `/dev/sdXY` is the partition name and `/path/to/mountpoint` is a convenient empty folder. To make an empty folder in `/media`, create a new one with `sudo mkdir /media/mountpoint && sudo chown -R $USER /media/mountpoint`.

Comment: depending on the version of ubuntu, removable devices are no longer in media http://askubuntu.com/questions/336518/why-has-ubuntu-moved-the-default-mount-points