# External Hard disk being mounted in a different path after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, mount

I have upgraded my  Ubuntu  12.04  to 14.04. After the upgrade I noticed that my external hard disk is being mounted in a separate path.

Earlier, It used to be in  `/media/u10`.  Now I see it is mounted on  `/media/walt/u10`.

walt is the root username for my ubuntu PC.

I have to change it manually by running this below  command everytime,

```
sudo  mount -B   /media/walt/u10     /media/u10
```

How to resolve this issue , I don't want to run above command everytime.

Comment: Any particular problem with it being mounted there?

Comment: Yes. I have virtual box machines and all related disks in that drive. And Virtualbox machines don't start in that new location.

Comment: You can add an entry to /etc/fstab.

Comment: What  should be the fstab entry for this hard disk. WHen I do df -h for this  hard disk it shows below.....  

 /dev/sdb1            1.8T  240G  1.5T  14% /media/walt/u10

Comment: The linux file system standard changed the location for mounting remoable media - you can over ride it if you wish

Comment: It's just a workaround, but what about a symbolic link from the desired to the actual location? `sudo ln -s walt/u10 /media`. That's less invasive and permanent than adding an fstab entry.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/214646/how-to-configure-the-default-automount-location --- it has the solution in the second (not the accepted) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `blkid` command to get the UUID of the partition on the external disk:

```
$ sudo blkid | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="cdff3742-9d03-4bc1-93e3-ae50708474f2" TYPE="ext4"
```

The corresponding `fstab` entry will look like

```
UUID="cdff3742-9d03-4bc1-93e3-ae50708474f2" /media/u10 auto defaults,nofail 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple configuration would be this:

```
UUID="01CCD01C97D32280" /media/etc   ntfs       0              0       0
```

Here

- **/media/etc** is the folder where you want to mount your disk
- ntfs is the format of partition.
- Rest values wouldn't be neccessary for plain auto-mounting and if you want advanced configuration, manual is always there.   [Link to the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) .

Here UUID of any partition can be found out using:

```
sudo blkid
```

Complete procedure would be:

- `sudo blkid`, to get the UUID of the disk, you can use disk-name too, but I prefer it.
- `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`edit the fstab file.
- Append this line, to the end of configuration file.
  `UUID="01CCD01C97D32280" /media/etc   ntfs       0              0       0`

Hope it would help :) :)