# Mount Android phone for another user

Tags: mount, android, mtp

There are 2 Android phones connected to a particular machine, and they're mounted automatically in `/run/user/<my_uid>/gvfs/`.

That's cool and all, but unfortunately I need them to be mounted under another user's directory because a particular service which copies files to and from the devices uses Python's `os.getuid()` to get the current user's uid, but the service is run with that other user which we'll call "testuser".

What rule could I edit that would mount the devices in `/run/user/<testuser_uid>/gvfs/` instead?

Comment: see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214646/how-to-configure-the-default-automount-location

Comment: Using symbolic links is very clever! Thanks for that. The only issue that I'm facing is folder permissions of the two uid folders, but that's a different issue and it should be fairly easily solvable. Thanks again!

Comment: You know, the permissions thing is actually still somewhat complicated, and [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8159/mounting-usb-disks-automatically-how-it-works) would've been really helpful if someone answered. I just don't understand fundamentally where the user gets decided when gvfs-fuse-daemon mounts something, or if those permissions can be configured so I can use symlinks