# How to change permissions of automount?

Tags: mount, permissions, automount, udev, udisks

I set up a Ubuntu 14.04 machine for my family.

I noticed that when I insert a USB key it gets automounted to /media/$username/$volumename. /media/$username has an ACL that only allows $username to access the medium, causing problems when switching users. The new user has no rights whatsoever, so the only options are pulling out the USB key and re-inserting it.

Googling, I found this: https://askubuntu.com/a/276670. Using this udev rule I managed to tell udisks2 to automount media to /media/$volumename. Still /media/$volumename has permissions set to 700, causing the same problems.

I suspect that udisks2 uses a restrictive umask for automounts. Does anyone know how to change the umask? Is there a possibility to set the group of the mount directory (so that I could use 770 permissions)?

/etc/fstab is not a solution, since this has to work for automounts of unknown media.

Comment: is there a reason not to use chmod / chown?

Comment: It’s not possible to change permissions on a FAT filesystem, they have to be set when mounting.

Comment: Of /media I mean

Comment: $volumename still will be 700.

Comment: Luc, can you reformat your USB flash memory as ext3 or ext4 ? This would make things very much easier as you could then give it a tag (can be done with FAT32 as well) and more importantly use  `sudo chmod 770` on it. Just an idea ...

Comment: You should be able to adjust the MODE in the `udev` rule.  umask **007** should be equivalent to 770.

Comment: @Cbhihe I can’t reformat anything, since this is supposed to work with USB keys from other people, too.

Comment: @earthmeLon I cannot check currently, but I think this will only change the permissions of the /dev/* file? The following link makes me believe that mount masks are hardcoded into udisks2 :-( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606193

Comment: Yes, `MODE=----` only sets "permissions for the device node. Every specified value overrides the compiled-in default value."